# Is it possible to replace a table cell without deleting it with javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to replace a table cell without deleting it with javascript or jQuery?  For example, if I have a table with several rows, each row having 5 cells, could I change the first cell of the first row through assignment instead of removing the cell and then inserting a new one?

EDIT (simplified):

```
<table>
    <tr id="currentRowId1" name="currentRowId1">
        <td style="text-align:center">
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center">
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center">
            <input type="submit" onclick="changeOrder()" />
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center">
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="currentRowId2" name="currentRowId2">
        <td style="text-align:center">
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center">
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center">
            <input type="submit" onclick="changeOrder()" />
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center">
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

js

```
function changeOrder(){
var row = document.getElementById("currentRowId1");
var otherRow = document.getElementById("currentRowId2");
row.cells[0] = otherRow.cells[0];
}
```

Comment: Yes! Well, *probably*. What do you want to do it? Give us some idea of your use-case, and what you've already tried. Maybe a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/), to help us see what you're working with? Post your HTML/JavaScript...help *us* to help **you**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is acutally no need to work with `innerHTML` here. You could replace the two elements like this:

```
var
  a = document.getElementById('currentRowId1').cells[0],
  e = document.getElementById('currentRowId2').cells[0],
  e1 = e.nextSibling;

a.parentNode.replaceChild(e, a);
e1.parentNode.insertBefore(a, e1);
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/X4zzb/1/

Comment: var copyFrom = targetRow.cells[0].cloneNode(true);
    var pasteTo = row.cells[0];
    pasteTo.parentNode.replaceChild(copyFrom, pasteTo);
    //this code copies the cell from row into the cell in targetRow without erasing the original row's cell.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this.  You can set the inner html of the cell as fabianhjr pointed out.  You can also build a new element in javascript/jquery and use [jquery's replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) method.

You can use other jquery methods that will **replace** the cells, [clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) and [before()](http://api.jquery.com/before/) or [after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/) I know this isn't what you asked for just pointing out other options.

Example #1:

```
var me = $("#cellId");
var newHtml = $("<div>blah blah blah</div>");
me.replaceWith(newHtml);
```

Example #2:

```
var me = $("#cellId");
var clone = me.clone();
 // do some cool things with the clone change html whatever
me.replaceWith(clone);
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid having to delete the table cells which is what would be required if I used before or after.  I am not trying to produce multiple cells which are the same.  If I used clone() how would I then replace my current cell with the clone?

Comment: If there is a lot of data in the table cell that you want to manipulate then clone is very nice to create a copy of this inner html and manipulate it.  Then just call replaceWith.  I'll add in an edit.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know which jQuery .js script in asp.net holds the replaceWith() definition?

Comment: I'll admin that I'm no asp.net expert but in most situations I'm familiar with jquery.js is just one file usually jquery-#.#.#.js or jquery-#.#.#.min.js

Comment: Hm, maybe this is a bug in asp.net, I am going to open a separate question.  Firebug tells me "replaceWith() is not a function" and I have <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.jquery-1.4.4.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: That's quite an old version of jquery it may not have replaceWith().  jquery is up to 1.7.1 now.  You could look into updating your jquery but I'll let you know that not everything jquery related always works with the upgrades and going from 1.4.4 to 1.7.1 is a pretty big jump.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change whats inside it you can use..

```
document.getElementById('nameofyourcell').innerHTML = 'content';
```

Comment: Thank you, this does work, however I was hoping to preserve the attributes.

Comment: Fair enough. Looks like you found a solution above, however, another possibility may be hiding and showing elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just assign the cell equal to something else like you tried in this line:

```
row.cells[0] = otherRow.cells[0];  // doesn't work
```

However, once you have a reference to the cell you can change what is inside it, e.g., to copy the contents from one cell to another:

```
row.cells[0].innerHTML = otherRow.cells[0].innerHTML;
```

You can also create, amend or remove the children of the cell via the reference to the cell.

If you are using jQuery there are a number of methods that achieve the same sort of thing, e.g., the following is equivalent to the above (but less efficient):

```
$(row.cells[0]).html( $(otherRow.cells[0].html() );
```

Comment: This will not move attributes over :(  It is a good suggestion.

Comment: How could I assign something to the node which is at row.cells[0]?

Comment: Yes, that's true about the attributes, though in your example the attributes were the same anyway.

Comment: See above comment, although my assignment was not proper, it IS possible to assign a cell equal to something else using .replaceChild().